# How to limit the products from the compare in drupal?

Tags: commerce

I am working with the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and the [Commerce product comparison](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_comparison) module. Here I need to limit the products.

How do I limit the products from the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this through [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Event: After udpdating an already existing line item

Conditions:
1/ data comparison: commerce-line-item:type = product
2/ data comparison: commerce-line-item:commerce-product:type = Your given product type
3/ data comparison: commerce-line-item:quantity is greater than 1

Action:
- set data value: commerce-line-item:quantity 1
- display custom message